# If there are no crontabs, does /etc/cron.* run?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I've set up an Ubuntu server and deleted a user Ubuntu that happened to be there after imaging.

There are no crontabs for root or my user. Does that mean nothing from `/etc/crontab.*` runs? Will I have to call those cron jobs from a root crontab?

Comment: There should be the system-wide crontab, `/etc/crontab`; this is *not* root's crontab, it's the system-wide crontab (and has a slightly different format). The scripts in `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily` etc. are run from the system-wide crontab using [`run-parts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/run-parts.8.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in the [`cron(8)` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/cron/cron.8) (when you read that, consider that anything Debian-specific also applies to Ubuntu). In particular:

> `cron` searches its spool area (`/var/spool/cron/crontabs`) for crontab files (which are named after accounts in `/etc/passwd`); crontabs found are loaded into memory. Note that crontabs in this directory should not be accessed directly — the crontab command should be used to access and update them.
>
> `cron` also reads `/etc/crontab`, which is in a slightly different format (see [`crontab(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/cron/crontab.5)). In Debian, the content of `/etc/crontab` is predefined to run programs under `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly` and `/etc/cron.monthly`. This configuration is specific to Debian, see the note under **DEBIAN SPECIFIC** below.
>
> Additionally, in Debian, `cron` reads the files in the `/etc/cron.d` directory. `cron` treats the files in `/etc/cron.d` as in the same way as the `/etc/crontab` file (they follow the special format of that file, i.e. they include the user field). However, they are independent of `/etc/crontab`: they do not, for example, inherit environment variable settings from it.

The default `/etc/crontab` is [as follows](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-cron/pkg-cron.git/tree/debian/crontab.main):

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

(with additional support for `anacron` thrown in).

Thus even if no users have user-specific crontabs, there are still a number of places cron jobs can be specified on Debian derivatives. They are handled in a variety of ways, as described above; anything in `/etc/cron.d` will be interpreted directly by `cron`, but the contents of `/etc/cron.monthly`, `weekly`, `daily` and `hourly` are run by the corresponding instruction in `/etc/crontab`, or by `anacron` if that’s installed (for daily, weekly and monthly jobs).

The reflects the various roles of cron jobs. `/etc/cron.d` allows packages to drop cron jobs with cron specifiers and have them run. `/etc/cron.monthly` etc. allow packages and system administrators to drop scripts or binaries *without* cron specifiers and have them run at some regular interval, with no need for precise control over the exact moment at which they run. Per-user crontabs allow users to define their own jobs, with explicit validation (using the `crontab` command) to ensure that the format is valid before the system attempts to use them.